# Hibernate Panache update multiple rows query

Tags: quarkus

Is there an approach more in line with the language specifications to update multiple entities rather than directly accessing the class JpaOperations?

I want to execute something like `UPDATE FROM Notificacao set dataHoraExclusao = ?1`  where `dataHoraExclusao` is `null`.

The follow code execute fine, but is the best approach?

`JpaOperations.executeUpdate("UPDATE FROM Notificacao set dataHoraExclusao = ?1  where dataHoraExclusao is null", LocalDateTime.now());`

`Notificacao` is a `PanacheEntity`.

Comment: Hey, please be more specific about what you mean by "best approach?" are you looking for more efficiency? More inline with the language?

Comment: All operations using a `PanacheEntity` are in respective class or object.
Ex:
Persist `Notificacao`:
`Notificacao notificacao = new Notificacao();
notificacao.persist();`

Find `Notificacao`:
`Notificacao.listAll()`

However, a update query cant be done using `Notificacao` class or object

Source: [ORM with Panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache)

Comment: Quarkus 1.1 contains an update method: [PR](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/5753)